# Convert int array to string variable

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an integer array that keeps binary numbers 0 and 1 in itself. I want to convert my integer array to a string variable in java. How can I do it?

Comment: @HotLicks.. You prabably mean `Arrays` class? Its an Integer array.

Comment: @RohitJain -- But if he wants to format integers he wants the Integer class.  (Or he could just use print formatting, but we won't go into that.)

Comment: @HotLicks.. Well, what is needed is, either the `Array` can be directly converted to string using `Arrays.toString` method, or, it can be iterated upon, and each integer can be appended into a `StringBuilder`. So, Integer class really doesn't come into action in this case. I hope that makes it clear.

Answer (score 6):

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 0, 1, 0 };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arr.length);
for (int i : arr) {
  sb.append(i);
}
String s = sb.toString(); // 1010
```

If you don't mind having brackets around your string, and your numbers separated by a comma, you can use `Arrays.toString` as suggested by others.

Answer (score 6):

Probably [Arrays.toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29) is what you are looking for.

```
final int[] sample = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
final String arrayStr = Arrays.toString (sample);
System.out.println (arrayStr);
```

This should print [1, 2, 3].

Here is a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/4PNXwy) for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it:

```
String stringVar = java.util.Arrays.toString( intArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it manually like this

```
private static String format(int[] array) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean needSeparator = false;
    for (int number : array) {
        if (needSeparator) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        if (number != 0) {
            sb.append("true");
        } else {
            sb.append("false");
        }
        needSeparator = true;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That would be especially useful if you want to use a special format. Above example will produce strings like `"true, false, true"`

And a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/vg3quF).

Edit: oops, `true` should be `!= 0`, not `!=1`. Corrected in above code, broken in fiddle